# Adapting Cato's motto for today

Tags: grammar-choice

I need some help with the grammar here, I'm interested in learning Latin so I have been lurking around here for a bit, but I haven't really started, yet. (Well, I have had a couple of false starts).

I would like to adapt Cato the elder's famous motto for the times we live in now by exchanging *Carthago* with *Corona*:

*Ceterum autem censeo Carthaginem esse delendam* or the abbreviated form *Carthāgō dēlenda est*

What would it be? (And why).

Answer (score 9):

Sticking with just *corona*, you'd have:

1. *Corona delenda est*
2. *Censeo Coronam esse delendam*

You should know that *corona* is actually a Latin word meaning "crown", "garland", or "wreath". If you wanted this to be recognizable by the larger community, you'd probably want to adopt the scientific name, *coronavirus*. It's of course a made up compound, but *virus* is also a Latin word meaning "poison" or "slime" (obviously they didn't know about viruses in ancient Rome). It's neuter, so it would look instead like this:

1. *Coronavirus delendum est*
2. *Censeo Coronavirus esse delendum*

Comment: See also [this thread on the name](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13379/what-should-the-corona-virus-be-called-in-latin). You should note that if you choose the top answers, the grammar would remain the same as the second set (so *virus coronarium/coronatum delendum...*).

Answer (score 6):

The word *Corona* means *crown* or *garland* in Latin. The nominative (which serves as the subject) is *Corona*, and the accusative (the direct object, or object of certain prepositions) is *Coronam*. These forms would correspond with the nominative *Carthago* and the accusative *Carthaginem*. Therefore, the first sentence would be:

> *Ceterum autem censeo Coronam esse delendam.*

This is an example of [indirect discourse](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/tenses-infinitive-indirect-discourse), which consists of a main verb, in this case *censeo* (*I think* or *consider*), followed by a combination of the accusative (*Coronam*) and an infinitive (*esse* — *to be*).

The complement of the infinitive is *delendam*, which means basically *worthy of destruction* — often translated with *should be destroyed,* *must be destroyed* or *is to be destroyed*. (**Note:** the idea that it *should be*, *must be* or *is to be* comes from the fact that it's in the [gerundive](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive) form of *deleo*, which means *to destroy.*)

Simplifying this:

> ***Censeo Coronam esse*** *delendam*.
>
> I consider that Corona is to be destroyed.

In the other sentence, *Carthago* is the nominative case, so it would be simply:

> *Corona delenda est*.
>
> Corona is to be destroyed.

It's also good to note that the gerundive *delenda/delendam* (an [adjective](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/formation-adjectives) form of the verb) has to agree in gender, number and case with the noun it's modifying. In these sentences, it's in the feminine singular form (to agree with *Corona*), and it's ending changes to correspond to the case (whether *nominative* or *accusative*).

Answer (score 1):

Viruses were first identified in the 19th. Century. These, viral infections, of course, being different from bacterial diseases e.g. bubonic plague. Therefore I was surprised to find Oxford giving, (Latin) "virus" (a neuter noun) = "virus".

In Cato's quote "Carthago" (feminine, nominative) takes the accusative (direct object) after "censeo" = "I consider/ believe that". Neuter nouns are the same in the accusative as in the nominative, therefore, substitute neuter-accusative, "Coronavirus" ["corona" is the Latin word for "crown" (the spiky-structure of this species)] for feminine-accusative, "Carthaginem". Of course this changes feminine accusative "delendam" to the neuter equivalent, "delendum".

I'm not happy with "virus" = "venom"; "malignant quality"; "secretion with medical or magical potency".  A better word the Romans certainly knew--"morbus" = "disease", a masculine noun. In the accusative, "morbum", giving "Coronamorbum" for your substitution.

Thanks to Joonas for previous Q:[What should the corona virus be called in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13379/1982), which includes suggestions for Latin names for Coronavirus. As I have suggested "morbus" already, a possibility could be:

> Coronavirus = "morbus cum acutis sudibus praefixis" =

"a disease with established sharp spikes". This is a little long-winded. Perhaps, truncating:

> Coronavirus = "morbus cum sudibus" = "disease with spikes".

Giving:

> ceterum autem censeo morbum cum sudibus delendum esse

EDIT 17/5/2021:

Alternatively, "morbus sudium" = "disease of spikes":

> ceterum autem censeo morbum sudium delendum esse.

Research has shown that it is the spikes, attaching the virus to cells, in the body, that make this disease so lethal.

Comment: There's a separate [question about translating the name of the virus to Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13379/79). If you want to call it other than *corona*, which is well justified, I recommend reading through the suggestions and thoughts in that question.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta:  I recall that Q. Your suggestion " the crowned virus" implies, in English, that the disease has benefitted from a royal-coronation; it has been honoured in some way. How about "morbus cum sudibus acutis praefixis" = "diseae with established sharp spikes"?

Comment: I wouldn't say at all that there is anything royal or honoured about it, and I just edited my answer to clarify. I just meant "equipped with crown", which is what the name of the virus is quite literally trying to say. But there are a lot of other answers there, too. // I should also point out that the present question was about adapting something for today, so using words in their modern meanings seems necessary.

Comment: You're right that you would just substitute *Coronavirus* for *Carthaginem*, but you would also have to change the gerundive to agree with it. That's an equally important part!

Comment: @cmw: Well-spotted.

Comment: @tony Can you add a clear translation suggestion to your answer? Making it bold or putting it in a quote box would help make it stand out. The conclusion of your answer is not very clear, but could be clarified easily, I think.